# Why am I getting a segmentation fault error when searching throught the file the second time?

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define BUFSIZ 6
```

In here I search a file for a 3 char code and if the code matches the token it should output what code you entered.

```
void country_search(char code[6], FILE *dir, FILE *BAC_ptr){

    char *token_off;
    char *token;
    char buf[512];

    while (!feof(dir)){
        if (fgets(buf, 512 , dir)){
            token = strtok(buf,"1234567890");
            while (token != NULL){
                token = strtok(NULL,"1234567890");
                code = strtok(code,"\n");
                if ((strcmp(code,token)) == 0){
                printf("token: %s\n", token);
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {

    char code[6];

    FILE *BAC_ptr;
    BAC_ptr = fopen("BinaryAllCountries.dat", "r");
    FILE *D_ptr;
    D_ptr = fopen("directory.dat", "r");

    fprintf(stdout, "Hello! welcome to the country database press type in: quit[enter] to quit at anytime\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "enter character code of the country you want:\n ");
    fgets(code, BUFSIZ, stdin);
```

When I use the while loop it asks for the first input then takes it, runs through the country_search() method then comes back, and the 2nd time it gives me a segmentation fault error and I can't figure out why.

```
        while (strcmp(code, "quit\n") != 0) {
        fprintf(stdout, "enter another character code of the country you want: \n");
            country_search(code, D_ptr, BAC_ptr);
            fgets(code, BUFSIZ, stdin);
        }   
}
```

here is my directory.dat file

```
ABW3739AFG1511AGO43AIA3690ALB2635AND2654ANT4227ARE2547ARG5281ARM1532ASM4607ATA1336ATF1392ATG3721AUS4631AUT2675AZE1556BDI170BEL2717BEN62BFA149BGD1600BGR2775BHR1574BHS3759BIH2753BLR2695BLZ3797BMU3816BOL5302BRA5324BRB3778BRN1639BTN1620BVT1357BWA84CAF252CAN3837CCK4691CHE3597CHL5344CHN1684CIV355CMR193COD327COG307COK4715COL5367COM288CPV216CRI3887CUB3906CXR4658CYM3863CYP1703CZE2825DEU2956DJI376DMA3926DNK2846DOM3958DZA22ECU5389EGY396ERI447ESH1275ESP3519EST2867ETH470FIN2913FJI4740FLK5416FRA2934FRO2892FSM4857GAB489GBR3646GEO1745GHA529GIB2975GIN549GLP4044GMB509GNB574GNQ426GRC2996GRD4023GRL4004GTM4068GUF5442GUM4786GUY5459HKG1768HMD1433HND4109HRV2796HTI4087HUN3058IDN1813IND1790IOT122IRL3099IRN1832IRQ1851ISL3078ISR1871ITA3117JAM4130JOR1912JPN1892KAZ1936KEN592KGZ1980KHM1662KIR4806KNA4328KOR2356KWT1956LAO1998LBN2019LBR632LBY668LCA4352LIE3162LKA2380LSO613LTU3185LUX3208LVA3137MAC2037MAR818MCO3288MDA3270MDG691MDV2081MEX4174MHL4834MKD3231MLI731MLT3249MMR2125MNG2103MNP5001MOZ843MRT755MSR4194MTQ4153MUS776MWI712MYS2060MYT796NAM864NCL4900NER884NFK4965NGA907NIC4250NIU4940NLD3314NOR3334NPL2145NRU4874NZL4925OMN2189PAK2213PAN4270PCN5065PER5498PHL2262PLW5018PNG5048POL3355PRI4295PRK2171PRT3377PRY5481PSE2236PYF4769QAT2280REU927ROM3399RUS3433RWA947SAU2307SDN1142SEN1025SGP2330SGS1485SHN970SJM3552SLB5111SLE1073SLV3983SMR3455SOM1095SPM4388STP1004SUR5519SVK3477SVN3499SWE3572SWZ1165SYC1047SYR2400TCA4500TCD270TGO1206THA2468TJK2445TKL5129TKM2513TMP1724TON5146TTO4464TUN1227TUR2487TUV5164TWN2421TZA1188UGA1248UKR3617UMI5208URY5540USA4529UZB2572VAT3036VCT4433VEN5564VGB4555VIR4581VNM2594VUT5228WLF5257WSM5083YEM2614YUG3671ZAF1122ZMB1295
```

Comment: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/1606345)

Comment: show your input and output

Comment: can it be that you enter a 5 character country code?

Comment: The second time around you are already at the end of that file.

Comment: `code = strtok(code,"\n");` when `code` is an argument defined as `char code[5]`  ?

Comment: Note that you do not `rewind` your files once they have been read (although I don't think that the program crashes for that reason)

Comment: `code` only has space for 5 chars, but "quit\n" requires 6 (counting the '\0' and the end).

Comment: What is `BUFSIZ`?

Comment: the BUFSIZ is 6

Comment: @RadLexus yes thank you, flew by my head

Comment: Why is `BUFSIZ` 6 if the actual size of the buffer is only 5?!

Comment: i have changed it to 6 as @JohnnyMopp made a good point, sorry I didnt mention that

Comment: @RadLexus when i use the rewind() function i still get the segmentation fault

Comment: Yes. It was an observation of mine but I could not make it follow through on to a crash -- @StephanLechner is correct in this.

Comment: Can we see the actual code you are having the problem with then?

Comment: @infixed yea i need to get rid of the \n char as the token will not have one. even if i do get rid of that line the seg. fault still happens

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, what do u mean? this is the code everything is here.

Comment: Anyhow, using `strtok` twice that way should not work reliably. But also ... not crash. Hm.

Comment: @jhowe So `BUFFSIZ` is 6 and the size of the actual buffer is only 5? What's the mystery then?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz no i changed it all to 6

Comment: Okay, then don't claim you're showing us the actual code you're having the problem with. I looked at it again and it says "`char code[5];`". Can you update your question to show the *actual* code you're having the problem with? And include relevant bits like `BUFSIZ`.

Comment: Your debugger should tell you where the segfault happens. Learn how to use a debugger. It's time now. Really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program crashes at the following line ([`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org) told me right away):

```
if ((strcmp(code,token)) == 0){
```

Why? Because you test *too soon* for a `NULL`:

```
    while (token != NULL){
        token = strtok(NULL,"1234567890"); <- right here TOKEN can be set to NULL!
        /* code = strtok(code,"\n"); MUST be moved elsewhere*/
         if ((strcmp(code,token)) == 0){
           printf("token: %s\n", token);
         }
```

To solve, just insert a `NULL` check at the appropriate place:

```
while (token != NULL) {
    token = strtok(NULL,"1234567890");
    if (token)
    {
        if (strcmp(code,token) == 0){ /* no need for extra parens here */
          printf("token: %s\n", token);
        }
    }
}
```

A few extra remarks:

1. `BAC_PTR` is not used.
2. move the line that removes the `\n` from `code` somewhere safe. Preferably outside the loop ... but even better,
3. entering an empty line will make this crash as well. So remove the `\n` directly after input, then test for an empty line.
4. your buffer of 512 is no good. It's too small for the entire `directory.dat` file, and one of the 3-letter codes gets cut in half.

Comment: BAC_ptr will be used just havent gotten there yet and yea i just put 512 for a random number right now will change that thank you. I shall use valgrind I will look it up thank you.

Comment: @jhowe: it won't harm you to do so, but I've learned how to interpret `valgrind`'s at times cryptic messages. Locate a good debugger – `gdb` sounds just nice for you – so you can step through your code one line at a time, and see variables change value while you do that.